# Magento Admin 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: magento2, error

When I go to my Magento Admin it say:

503 Service Unavailable

The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.

Additionally, a 503 Service Unavailable error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

But it is not maintenance because I have disabled it and don't see maintenance.flag in root or var

It's out of the blue something else while I did nothing

Anybody please know?

Thanks

Comment: this file is probably hidden like `/var/.maintenance.flag`

Comment: @MagenX Thanks so much for your response, that's the strange part here, I can see the hidden files and there is nowhere .maintenance.flag , so that's why my question, how come ? I really don't know, really hope to get help :)